# When to use Form authentication and windows authentication in asp.net and why?

Tags: asp.net

When to use form-authentication and windows authentication and why ? 
if i used to login using DB then how authentication will work

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, The name itself defined everything.

In **Forms Authentication**, your application have a Login Form/Page, where user should enter User name and Password to authenticate. Just like Gmail, Facebook.

In **Windows Authentication**, the application will take your system User name and Password to validate.

While you open your system, it ask to choose which user(if your system have multiple users), then you need to enter password to go inside. That credential will take in windows authentication.

It is already explained details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443888/windows-authentication-vs-forms-authentication)

**If i used to login using DB then how authentication will work ?**

Suppose your application will access/used inside an organization or intranet, it would be better to use Windows Authentication.

If your appliaction will access/used globally, then you need Form Authentication.